# What are some good uses of the while statement?

Tags: javascript

Whenever I think of using the `while loop`, I don't see why I can't just use an `if statement` instead. I know that a while loop runs 'while' a given statement is true, but if the condition is terminated inside the block instantaneously, then I cannot visualize anything happening 'while' something is true. If anyone can give me examples of how/why I should use a `while loop`. It would be very appreciated.

Comment: I dont know how an `if` statement could come close to replacing a `while` loop honestly :?

Comment: My bad, it doesn't seem to exist in javascript.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm going to try to give you a very high-level answer because I think it will be easier to grasp intuitively.

Think of all algorithms as recipes. A typical recipe might have parts that look like the following:

- If the peanut has a shell, separate it from the shell
- Beat an egg until it is whipped and bubbly
- Take 5 onions and chop each of them in half

These types of directions have you do tasks in different ways.

The first one is really an "if" statement. You do something if a condition (peanut has a shell) is true. You literally do:

```
if (not shelled) {
  shell the peanut! // happens once
}
```

---

The second one is a while loop. You beat the egg *while* it is not whipped and bubbly. You do the same thing over and over (whipping) continuously, and you look at it (over and over) when doing this to check and see if it has turned very bubbly. Once it gets bubbly and whipped enough, you stop. When you stop it is because you have passed your "While" condition. An important thing to note is that before you start, you don't necessarily know just how many "beats" of an egg it takes to get it whipped. You just have to do it many times and check (with your eyes) many times. You literally do:

```
while(not whipped enough) {
  beat egg! // happens over and over
}
```

Just like in recipes, you don't want someone doing a certain action until the end of time, so you must always make sure your while loops have sensible stopping conditions. Most while loops depend on something changing inside of the loop and will stop when that thing has changed enough.

---

The third recipe example is a for loop. For each onion you have (5) you do something once to that one onion. You literally do:

```
for (onions 1 to 5) {
  Chop an onion! // done 5 times total, once per onion
}
```

Comment: +1 for a very good illustration showing the difference and correct usage between the three

Comment: This really helps me visualize what a while loop is really doing. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`while` is a looping construct, not just another form of `if`

```
var i = 0;

while ( i < 10 ) {
    //this stuff will happen until
    //i < 10

    // usually you iterate the counter so it
    // eventually breaks the loop because
    // i < 10 is no longer true
    i++;
}
```

this does the same thing as this

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    //this stuff will happen until
    //i < 10
}
```

***Good use case for while***

generally a `for` loop is used when the number of iterations that need to take place is known, so generally when you're iterating over an array and you know the length of the array `for` is a good choice because you can set the amount of iterations explicitly.

a better use case for `while` is when the amount of iterations is not static (known) and/or  you are waiting for an event to occur to break the loop.

Answer (score 1):

A `while` loop will execute **over and over** as long as the conditions are met, being that it will go to infinity if the condition never changes.

An `if` will execute **once** when the condition is met

Comment: haha, I got stuck on thinking about a `for` loop. Fixed my wording, doesn't change my answer though.

Answer (score 1):

`while` will keep running until the condition becomes false.
If the condition is still true at the end of the block, the loop will run all over again.

`if` will only run once.

Answer (score 1):

Well an `if statement` will not loop back around. It will only ever happen once unless you put it in a loop. A `while statement` will happen more than once as long as the statement is still true.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to create an infinite loop a while loop will do the trick

```
var done=false;
while(!done){
    alert("I am annoying");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `for` statement can be simulated with a while:

```
for(var i=0; i<length; i++) {}

// is the same as

var i=0;
while(i<length) {
    // stuff
    i++;
}
```

It is also used for loops like:

```
while(true) {
    // stuff... (like waiting for user input, analyzing some data until
    // it hits a brick wall and needs to quit)
    if(some_condition) {
        break;
    }
}
```

Or for other stuff:

```
while(a != b) {
    if(a > b) {
        a -= b;
    } else {
        b -= a;
    }
} // find the GCD of a and b
```

As you can see, it's very different from `if`, and solves other problems.